# How to supress the error of file redirection

Tags: shell

How can I suppress the following error

```bsh
if true </dev/tty 2>/dev/null; then
   read -r "$VARIABLE" </dev/tty
fi
```

seems not to ignore the error `can't open /dev/tty: No such device or address`. 
which was the purpose of the whole if clause. The error happens on the `if ...`

Comment: @Archemar, if /dev/tty cannot be opened for reading then `true < /dev/tty` will return a non-zero exit status and `true` will not be run. `tty` reports the name of tty device open on stdin if any. `true < /dev/tty` would check whether the process has a controlling terminal and that terminal device can be open for reading.

Comment: yes, I check after posting comment (hence deletion). I use `tty -s` in similar situation.

Comment: @Archemar, if it's to check whether stdin is a tty, `[ -t 0 ]` should be enough.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Redirect stderr first:

```
if true  2>/dev/null </dev/tty; then
   IFS= read -r "$VARIABLE" </dev/tty
fi
```

With `zsh`, you'd need:

```
if { true </dev/tty; } 2> /dev/null; then
   IFS= read -r "$VARIABLE" </dev/tty
fi
```

as upon redirection failures, zsh restores the fds before outputting the error messages (which kind of makes sense to me, but that means the behaviour is inconsistent as that restoring doesn't happen when redirecting an external command).

That's assuming you want to read a line from the controlling tty device of the process if there's one.

But that's not much different from

```
IFS= read -r "$VARIABLE" 2> /dev/null </dev/tty
```

If `/dev/tty` cannot be open, the command (here `read`) is not run.

You could also do it like:

```
{ IFS= read -r "$VARIABLE" < /dev/tty 2>&3 3>&-; } 3>&2 2> /dev/null
```

For stderr to be redirected to `/dev/null` before `/dev/tty` is opened, and restored afterwards for `read` (for `read` to still be able to report read errors if any).